# BGE Strange white artifacts on edges of objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, game-engine, texture-baking, baking

I just baked all my cycles materials onto my objects for a game i am making, but in the BGE there are strange white artifacts on some of the corners and edges of my model... I really have no idea what is causing this, so i am sorry i can't tell you more.
Here is a link to download the .blend --> https://www.mediafire.com/?5hhsfr4hdmkabf2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the UV/Image editor in which the interested part is shown?

Comment: My guess is teh bake margin got interrupted.. Check your bake settings and rebake.